# Swing Relations Indicator: Matching inside bar colour to previous bar

Tags: colors, bar-chart, pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm trying to make a three colour bar swing relations indicator for Trading View and would like the inside bar colour to match the color of the last or previous bar.

[SWING RELATIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyIED.png)

// "if previous bar is an inside bar match colour to last bar"

I'm not sure how to interigate the previous bar for its colour. Have been able to change the bar based on being an inside bar only, but not to match the last bar colour. Trading Higher, lower or outside i have sorted.

Thanks

```
//@version=5
indicator("3 Colour Bar Chart")

// INSIDE BARS: Match previous bar color
isInsideDown() => high < high[1] and low > low[1] and barcolor(color.red, 1)
isInsideUp() => high < high[1] and low > low[1] and barcolor(color.green, 1)
isInsideOut() => high < high[1] and low > low[1] and barcolor(color.blue, 1)

barcolor(isInsideDown() ? color.green : isInsideUp() ? color.red : isInsideOut() ? color.blue : na)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the color of a bar as below:

```
bar_is_green = (close >= open)
bar_is_red = not (bar_is_green)
```

Then to check the color of the previous bar, just use the [history referencing operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#history-referencing-operator).

`bar_is_green[1]` will tell you if the previous bar was green.